# All attributes of a tag which is not yet in the DOM

Tags: jquery

I have a JavaScript function that merges an html snipped that is NOT YET in the DOM , for example

```
<div class="one two"><input /><span name="abc">Text</span></div>
```

with a DOM node/tag

```
<div id="aaa" class="another"></div>
```

The result is:

```
<div id="aaa" class="one two another"><input /><span name="abc">Text</span></div>
```

I want to improve this function.

Until now I it does the following:

- It takes the class attribute of the first source tag and merges it with the target:

  ```
  classes = $(source).first().attr("class");
  this.addClass(classes);
  ```
- It appends the source child tags to the target:

  ```
  this.append($(source).first().children());
  ```

Now I want to add to this function:

```
   Take all attribute (not "class") of the first source tag and add it to the
   first target tag (overwrite if it exists).
```

The problem is, that I cannot take "attributes", because the source snipped is not yet in the DOM. The solution that I have until now is not very beautiful: For every very common attribute I have an extra line:

```
tabindex = $(source).first().attr("tabIndex");
this.attr("tabIndex", tabindex);

wrap = $(source).first().attr("wrap");
this.attr("wrap", wrap);
```

Has anybody an idea how to get all attributes of such an html snippet (first tag)?

**Update:**

Of course I could swap source and target:

- Read all attributes of the target DOM tag with "attributes".
- Add these attributes to the first tag of the snippet, which is not yet in the DOM.
- Replace the the DOM tag with the html snippet.

But is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Just a notice : if you add something to the dom and remove it immediately it's not rendered in the browser and it's fast.

Comment: Why not add the element with "display:none".  The element won't show up on the page and you can access all attributes of the hidden element(s).  When you are satisfied with the manipulation of the element you simply show() it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to read attributes from a fragment quite easily by accessing them from the actual DOM object:

```
​var $target = $('#aaa');​​​​​​​​
$source = $('<div class="one two"><input /><span name="abc">Text</span></div>');​

// iterate over attributes of $source
// we use $source.get(0) to get the DOM fragment itself
for (var i = 0, attributes = $source.get(0).attributes, item; item = attributes[i]; ++i) {
    if (item.name == 'class') {
        // special case for class
        $target.addClass(item.nodeValue);
    } else {
        // otherwise overwrite attribute of target with source
        $target.attr(item.name, item.nodeValue);
    }
}
// finally append the children from source
​$target.append($source.children());​
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought "attributes" would not work for snippets that are not in the DOM. So I learned something very important.